# numpy fromfile(count = -1) returns array of zeros on Mac OS for huge filesize

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am reading a file using numpy.fromfile:

```
mat1=numpy.fromfile("path/to/file", numpy.uint8, 40000, "")
```

this reads the file as I expect.

but when I read the entire file:

```
mat1=numpy.fromfile("path/to/file", numpy.uint8, -1, "")
```

this gives me an array of zeros. `[0,0,0,...,0,0,0]`

I tired: 
`numpy.count_nonzeros(mat1)` which gives 0

`size(mat1)` gives the exact size of the file in bytes. So it makes an array of the expected size, but its full of zeros.

Comment: Can this be reproduced on smaller files?

Comment: my file size is 2.5GB! Want to know if this is a good approach. I do not want to read character by character. Takes a lot of time.

Comment: That's odd... For whatever it's worth, I read in large (>10GB) binary files as an array `uint8`s this way very often.   Is it possible that the file is open for writing somewhere else?

Comment: Are you on OSX? There's an [open issue on numpy fromfile/tofile failing silently on large arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2806)

Comment: @JoeKington: anything to do with RAM size?

Comment: @MichaelJCox: yes i do use OSX.. any alternative?

Comment: @change - No, you'd get a `MemoryError` if there wasn't enough available RAM. As MichaelJCox mentioned, it looks like it's a bug, related to this: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2931  The pull request hasn't been merged yet, though.

Comment: @change did you check if the problem was your version (answer below)?

Comment: i do not remember the version now, but @MichaelJCox point was true then.

Comment: Per comment in linked bug, ` Depends what you are testing -- the bug only occured for filesizes over 2GB therefore the test doing the massive IO operation to verify that all is fine.` Try to install newest numpy...; or figure out how to e.g. split the data in chunks...

Comment: Guys: **state the versions of numpy** that fail, and also the version that merges the patch.

Answer (score 1):

This was apparently mitigated by OS X upgrades. The [original issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2931) pointed out by @MichaelJCox was closed, but a patch was never applied:

> Closing. The fix is to upgrade to Mavericks.